# Paragraph margins affecting floated block beside it

Tags: css, background, css-float, margins

I'm having a very frustrating situation with margins.. I have a div in the top of my markup that is floated to the right.

```
 .grey{
   float:right; 
   width:200px; 
 }
```

I need to apply some styles (background and margin) to the first paragraph after.

```
 .blue{
    background-color: blue; 
    margin: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Now I have to make the paragraph "overflow: hidden" so the background doesn't extend under the floated div, but I have 2 strange problems.

1. the margin doesn't seem to apply to the side of the paragraph that touches the float;
2. the margin seems to apply to the floated element beside it..

Here's a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteatom/Nkfzg/6/

Could anyone tell me how to get the margin space between the "Blue" element and the floated one? and could anyone tell me how to make my floated element not have these phantom margins?

Cheers,

whiteatom

Comment: Just to help you understand what's going on, the div appears to receive the top margin because it's actually body that's getting the margin, as a result of collapsing with the margin that you give to the first paragraph.

Comment: I don't think so.. If I take the margin off the first paragraph it goes away on both the floated and the blue div. I agree it appears to be applying to the body.. but if I take the float off the grey div it goes to the upper right corner - no margins.

Comment: That's happening because when you stop floating the div, the paragraph gets pushed down because it comes after the div in your HTML. When that happens, the p margin is no longer adjoining with the body margin, and so neither body nor div receive margin collapse. The p gets pushed away from the div instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a left margin to the floating element in order to space it away from the paragraph:

```
.grey {
    float: right; 
    width: 200px; 
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

As mentioned, margin collapse causes the top margin of your paragraph to affect the page body instead. This causes it to push both the paragraph and the floating element down.

To remove the top margin from the floating element, you have two options (choose only one):

- Cancel margin collapse by floating the body:

  ```
  body {
      float: left;
  }
  ```

  This causes the margin to affect only the paragraph. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Nkfzg/9)
- Apply a negative top margin to your floating element:

  ```
  .grey {
      float: right; 
      width: 200px; 
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: -10px;
  }
  ```

  Here, you're shifting the floating element up to counter the margin collapse, which remains in effect. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Nkfzg/10)

Answer (score 0):

If the `.grey` div is always going to be 200px wide, just change the margin of the `.blue` div to be `width + 10px`. Like so:

```
.blue {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px 210px 10px 10px;
};
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkfzg/7/).

Comment: I don't think that will work.. If the blue paragraph is farther down the page, I would want it to extend over the the page margin. The grey div is just a feature box, not a column. It just seems like this should be an easy thing to fix, but it's just not....